# What causes a com.sun.identity.agents.arch.AgentException with a message stating "invalid transport string" in a JBoss agent?

Tags: jboss, openam

> com.sun.identity.agents.arch.AgentException: Invalid transport string
>           at com.sun.identity.agents.util.TransportToken.initializeFromString(TransportToken.java:135)
>           at com.sun.identity.agents.util.TransportToken.(TransportToken.java:115)
>           at com.sun.identity.agents.common.SSOTokenValidator.validate(SSOTokenValidator.java:99)
>           at com.sun.identity.agents.realm.AmRealm.authenticate(AmRealm.java:141)
>           at com.sun.identity.agents.jboss.v40.AmJBossLoginModule.validatePassword(AmJBossLoginModule.java:88)
>           at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:249)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769)
>           at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
>           at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
>           at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579)
>           at org.jboss.security.plugins.auth.JaasSecurityManagerBase.defaultLogin(JaasSecurityManagerBase.java:552)
>           at org.jboss.security.plugins.auth.JaasSecurityManagerBase.authenticate(JaasSecurityManagerBase.java:486)
>           at org.jboss.security.plugins.auth.JaasSecurityManagerBase.isValid(JaasSecurityManagerBase.java:365)
>           at org.jboss.security.plugins.JaasSecurityManager.isValid(JaasSecurityManager.java:160)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JBossWebRealm.authenticate(JBossWebRealm.java:384)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:258)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:417)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Comment: Is there a question beside the stacktrace? a bit of context would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stacktrace it looks like you may try to use an application-client with your application that has enabled the AMRealm in its security-domain configuration (and/or AMRealm is the default security domain).

The transport string is basically the password that is being provided to the JAAS login module. I suppose you wanted to authenticate on your own (since the filter cannot be found on the stacktrace I'm guessing that this is not a web request..). Without any further info it is hard to help to diagnose your problem..

Comment: I apologize for this, but could you look at a similar question that I have? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441024/openam-opensso-httpservletrequest-loginuser-pass-fails-with-invalid-transp