# OpenAM / OpenSSO HttpServletRequest.login(user, pass) fails with "Invalid transport string". What does this mean?

Tags: java, tomcat7, openam, apache-tomee, opensso

I have two tomcat servers, one with OpenAM 12, one with the main web applications. Known: HTML pages authenticate without issue, programmatic login using the OpenAM java SDK works from within a servlet.

**What fails** is a call to **HttpServletRequest.login(username, password)**

This is the entry I have within the TomEE+ server:

```
    <Realm className="com.sun.identity.agents.tomcat.v6.AmTomcatRealm" debug="99"/>
```

Here is the error I see within the AM J2EEAgent debug log:

```
amRealm:01/29/2014 02:29:47:497 PM EST: Thread[http-bio-443-exec-3,5,main]
SSOTokenValidator: validate failed with exception
[AgentException Stack]
com.sun.identity.agents.arch.AgentException: Invalid transport string
        at com.sun.identity.agents.util.TransportToken.initializeFromString(TransportToken.java:135)
        at com.sun.identity.agents.util.TransportToken.<init>(TransportToken.java:115)
        at com.sun.identity.agents.common.SSOTokenValidator.validate(SSOTokenValidator.java:99)
        at com.sun.identity.agents.realm.AmRealm.authenticate(AmRealm.java:143)
        at com.sun.identity.agents.tomcat.v6.AmTomcatRealm.authenticate(AmTomcatRealm.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate(CombinedRealm.java:146)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERealm.authenticate(TomEERealm.java:43)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.doLogin(AuthenticatorBase.java:818)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.login(AuthenticatorBase.java:800)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:2621)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.login(RequestFacade.java:1065)
```

Comment: What other information can I provide to help isolate the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request#login fails for the username/password combination, because the agent defines its own Tomcat Realm definition (AmTomcatRealm) in the server.xml. The agent's realm does not use username/password combination for validating users as the credentials shouldn't even be present there (OpenAM performs the authentication and afterwards the password is long gone before you reach the actual protected application), it is actually a bit worrisome that you still have access to the user's password.

Since the agent should never actually know the user's password, it uses a transport string, that contains several information (amongst the session ID), it has a quite undocumented format, here is some link to the relevant source code:
https://svn.forgerock.org/openam/trunk/openam-agents/jee-agents/jee-agents-sdk/src/main/java/com/sun/identity/agents/util/TransportToken.java

Also, this is not a chicken-egg problem, as it is assumed that the JAAS login is performed by the agent itself, and it isn't really expected that the application would invoke login in the first place. In the agent settings (and in web.xml of course - see container documentation) there are ways to enable JAAS form login support and then the agent can take care of the JAAS integration without the need of knowing anything about the proprietary transport string format.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Unfortunately, this is a java heavy client that is accessing an unprotected servlet to login. The java application has the form information. It sends the username and password to the servlet. The servlet uses the java openam sdk to get a valid SSO token. I had hoped to somehow make tomcat use the httpservletrequest#login to make tomcat itself aware of this new user but from what you are telling me, since this application is doing this outside the box... I may not have any way of doing so.

Comment: So I guess the real question is: How 'SHOULD' a java heavy client implement its own form login, such that I do not have to use this backdoor way of validating to the user to openAM? Yes there is the OpenAM Java SDK (which I'm currently doing within the unprotected servlet), but how do I get subsequent servlet calls (that all send serialized java objects) to work, knowing who this user is and their existing roles?

Comment: As a side comment: Unless I've missed something, it seems that OpenAM is NOT geared towards applications that send serialized objects to protected servlets. I say this because I've noticed that when I have tried to protect a servlet, the openAM filter redirects me to a hidden form with the user name and password (is this the encrypted transport token string?). This redirect works fine with browsers but breaks any attempt to have a serialized object communications with the protected servlet.

Comment: I decided to create a different question for the above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21539197/what-is-the-correct-way-for-a-java-heavy-client-to-authenticate-with-an-openam-p

Answer (score 1):

In case of AgentRealm the 'password' is not the password, but the SSOTokenId from the SSO session.

Comment: Interesting. It just so happens that I do have access to the full iPlanetDirectoryPro string (I'm assuming that's the SSOTokenID). So I will try that. However, isn't this a chicken and the egg sort of problem? If I'm understanding this correctly, I can't go to a servlet request and use the #login(user, pass) UNLESS I've already authenticated the user through a different mechanism. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. I tried using the long SSO session id.